# Python Error, TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: numpy, opencv

Need help, please how to fix this

```
  File "c:\Users\Hakdog\Desktop\cyber_health\face_recognition.py", line 77, in face_recog
    img=recognize(img,clf,faceCascade)
  File "c:\Users\Hakdog\Desktop\cyber_health\face_recognition.py", line 66, in recognize
    coord=draw_boundary(img,faceCascade,1.1,10,(255,25,255),"Face",clf)
  File "c:\Users\Hakdog\Desktop\cyber_health\face_recognition.py", line 33, in draw_boundary
    cv2.rectangle(img(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple typo, there should be a comma after `img`, like:

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 3)
-----------------^
```